# Delete specific tables in all databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've written a script that deletes specific tables from one database.

```sql
-- Declare variable
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DbName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Declare Cursor with Tables and load data into
DECLARE cursor_tables CURSOR FOR SELECT
    [name]
FROM sys.objects o
WHERE o.name LIKE '%bak%'
AND o.name NOT LIKE 'dms%'
AND o.create_date < GETDATE()-60
AND o.type = 'u'

-- Run through cursor
OPEN cursor_tables
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tables INTO @TableName

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Create and run drop statement
        SET @sql = 'drop table ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tables INTO @TableName
    END

-- Delete cursor
CLOSE cursor_tables
DEALLOCATE cursor_tables
```

Now I want to extend that script so it deletes these tables from all databases. So I thought I'll pack this code into a second (nested) cursor to loop through that.

```
BEGIN TRY

    -- Declare variable
    DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @DbName NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @sql_db NVARCHAR(MAX)

    -- Declare Cursors with databases and load data into
    DECLARE cursor_db CURSOR FOR SELECT 
        name 
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb') 

    OPEN cursor_db
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_db INTO @DbName

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN

        -- Declare Cursor with Tables and load data into
        DECLARE cursor_tables CURSOR FOR SELECT
            name
        FROM sys.objects o
        WHERE o.name LIKE '%bak%'
        AND o.name NOT LIKE 'dms%'
        AND o.create_date < GETDATE()-60
        AND o.type = 'u'

        SET @sql_db = 'use '+ QUOTENAME(@DbName) --+ CHAR(13) + 'go'
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql_db

        OPEN cursor_tables
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tables INTO @TableName

        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN

            SET @sql = 'drop table ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
            FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tables INTO @TableName
        END

        CLOSE cursor_tables
        DEALLOCATE cursor_tables

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_tables INTO @DbName
    END;

    CLOSE cursor_db
    DEALLOCATE cursor_db

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
        --,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        --,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine;
END CATCH
```

Unfortunately I get an error message that the "cursor_tables" does not exist  in the line where I try to close that cursor. Can someone help me with that?

Thx in advance
Alex

Comment: You are `fetch`-ing from the "cursor_tables" after you have closed and deal-located it. I think you wanted to `fetch` the "cursor_db" instead.

Comment: I would try and use sp_foreachdb.

Comment: YES... YMD... that was the error! Thx

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would use Aaron Bertrand's [`dbo.sp_foreachdb`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) (instead of Microsoft' built in version), and pass a dynamic statement that is built and run. this is untested, but I beleive this will work:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'USE ?' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           N'SET @DSQL = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + ' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                          N''DROP TABLE '' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N'';''' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                   FROM sys.schemas s' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                        JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                   WHERE t.[name] LIKE N''%bak%''' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                     AND t.[name] NOT LIKE N''dms%''' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                     AND t.create_date < DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE())' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                     AND t.type = N''u''' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'                   FOR XML PATH(N''''),TYPE).value(''.'',''nvarchar(MAX)''),1,2,N'''');' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'EXEC sp_executesql @DSQL;';

EXEC master.dbo.sp_foreachdb @command = @SQL;
```

This looks confusing, but this effectively a dynamic statement inside a dynamic statement (that is run against every User database).

Comment: Hi, thx for the fast reply. I've also alredy seen that procedure, but did not know how to write the statement. I'll give that a try ...

Comment: I had to make a couple of corrections @scarabeaus, so make sure you use my latest version.

Comment: Just realised that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` doesn't have the create date, @scarabeaus, so need to fix that, apologies; give me 5.

Comment: Ok, give that a go @scarabeaus, switch to using the `sys` objects.

Comment: hi, thx for your help. Unfortunately I got the error message that the master.dbo.dp_foreachdb procedure is unknown. But I've found the error allready.

Comment: **d**p; i had a spelling mistake that was fixed in my last edit, @scarabeaus . Should be **s**p.

Comment: @Larnu Two questions.  1) Why do you choose Aaron's sp ?  2) Why construct the string with CRLFs  when a multi-line string is more readable ?   I simply find something like this much easier to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57732533/how-to-monitor-database-file-size-using-zabbix/57733243#57733243    Either way +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Aaron explains the advantages of his SP in the above link; he'll be far better explaining than I. And formatting. This is actually a dynamic dynamic statement, but using a multi-line string *can* throw the alignments all over the place. I actually explain some of that in my own article: [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql). I, personally, prefer the resulting SQL to be the most readable; as the dynamic SQL that is run is often the easiest to debug. The example you link is far simpler than the above too.

Comment: @Larnu I actually saw that article.  I just wasn't smart enough to connect the dots and see that it was YOU.  Well done!

Comment: Just a small something that's bugging me - you could just add another variable for line breaks instead of repeating the `NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)` all over the place. Other then that, great answer. Good to know you publish on sql server central, I'll have some reading to do this weekend :-)

Comment: It's something that was picked up in the discussion from the linked article, @ZoharPeled. It's more habit than anything; but i agree that a `nchar(2)` variable called `@CRLF` or something would make it more succinct.